# How can I have a sales order that is created via suitescript not save but open in browser>

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a button on a sales order that is supposed to create a new sales order using some of the field values from the old sales order in the new one. What I am needing to do is have have the new sales order NOT save but open in the browser so the user can complete some mandatory fields which would not be copied over. How can I do this?

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
*@NScriptType ClientScript
*/

define(['N/record', 'N/currentRecord'],  (record, currentRecord) => {
    function pageInit(){};
    function additionalBooking(context) {
        const rec = currentRecord.get();
        const client = rec.getValue({ fieldId: 'entity'});
        var objRecord = record.create({
            type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
            isDynamic: true,
            defaultValues: {
                entity: client
            }
        });
        var recordId = objRecord.save({
            enableSourcing: false,
            ignoreMandatoryFields: false
        });
    }
    return {
        pageInit: pageInit,
        additionalBooking: additionalBooking
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have mandatory fields you'll need the user to complete the Sales Order so it needs to be opened as new.

The fragment below opens a new initialized new sales order in either the current or a new blank window.
The `record.x` fields will be filled in automatically
the `custparam_y` fields can be detected by a User Event or Client script to to further setup in a Before Load user event pageInit client script.

```js
    var dsURL = url.resolveTaskLink({
        id: 'EDIT_TRAN_SALESORD',
        params:{
            entity: client,
            subsidiary:getLP('custrecord_eb_subsidiary'), // if needed
            cf:104, // custom form to use
            'record.custbody_prop_name': lpId,
            'record.department':getLP('custrecord_rif_prop_department'),
            'record.location':getLP('custrecord_rif_property_location'),
            custparam_type:'rr'
        }
    });
    
    window.location.href = dsURL;
    // or window.open(dsURL, '_blank');
```

If you are keeping the original SO open while you do create the second one you can use the reference supplied by window.open to 'watch' the new window for changes or you can use window.parent to trigger events from the newly opened page.