# How to get values from a record before creating a new record using url.resolveRecord?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a button that is created in a user event that - when clicked - should create a new transaction using value from the record the button was clicked on. My issue is that I do not know how I can get the values from the old record so I can use them for the new record.

**Button Script**

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType UserEventScript
*/
define([],
function() {
function beforeLoad(scriptContext) {
var form = scriptContext.form;
var cr = scriptContext.newRecord;

scriptContext.form.clientScriptModulePath = 'SuiteScripts/additional_booking.js';
        form.addButton({
            id: "custpage_addl_booking_button",
            label: "Add'l Booking",
            functionName: "additionalBooking"
            });
    
}
return {
beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
};
});
```

**Script to create new record**

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */

define(['N/record', 'N/currentRecord', 'N/url'], (record, currentRecord, url) => {
    function pageInit() {};

    function additionalBooking(context) {
        var redirectUrl = url.resolveRecord({
            recordType: 'salesorder',
            isEditMode: true,
                params: {
                  'entity': client,
                  'subsidiary': subsidiary
                }
          
          });
          
          window.open(redirectUrl);
                  }
    return {
        pageInit: pageInit,
        additionalBooking: additionalBooking
    };

});
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your client script can extract values and pass them to the new record as parameters.
If they are standard fields Netsuite will populate the new record with them. If they are non-standard fields you would set the values in a before load user event or in a pageInit client event.

This post: [How can I have a sales order that is created via suitescript not save but open in browser>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72807016/how-can-i-have-a-sales-order-that-is-created-via-suitescript-not-save-but-open-i/72807437#72807437) shows the formatting of the parameters for creating a new sales order.